# Fast way to calculate conditional function

Tags: python, performance, numpy

What is the most fast way to calculate function like

```
# here x is just a number
def f(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return np.log(x+1)
    else:
        return -np.log(-x+1)
```

One possible way is:

```
# here x is an array
def loga(x)
    cond = [x >= 0, x < 0]
    choice = [np.log(x+1), -np.log(-x+1)
    return np.select(cond, choice)
```

But seems numpy goes through array element by element.
Is there any way to use something conceptually similar to np.exp(x) to achieve better performance?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar sorry, I haven't possibility to check if yet. I will try in the nearest time and mark an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    def f(x):
        return (x/abs(x)) * np.log(1+abs(x))
```

Comment: Nice! This works. Good job on the math. Together with `numexpr` and/or re-using `abs(x)` should be the winner.

Comment: I suggest using `numpy.sign(x)` rather than `x/abs(x)`, to avoid a possible division by zero. `np.copysign(np.log(1 + abs(x)), x)` would be another way.

Comment: All this is pretty good. But functions like abs(), np.sign() can return 0. Marks solution is really nice, however, I would like to find solution faster than np.tanh(x). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

In cases like these, [`masking`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) helps -

```
def mask_vectorized_app(x):
    out = np.empty_like(x)
    mask = x>=0
    mask_rev = ~mask
    out[mask] = np.log(x[mask]+1)
    out[mask_rev] = -np.log(-x[mask_rev]+1)
    return out
```

Introducing [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) helps us further.

```
import numexpr as ne

def mask_vectorized_numexpr_app(x):
    out = np.empty_like(x)
    mask = x>=0
    mask_rev = ~mask

    x_masked = x[mask]
    x_rev_masked = x[mask_rev]
    out[mask] = ne.evaluate('log(x_masked+1)')
    out[mask_rev] = ne.evaluate('-log(-x_rev_masked+1)')
    return out
```

Inspired by [`@user2685079's post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277045/3293881) and then using the logarithmetic property : `log(A**B) = B*log(A)`, we can push in the sign into the log computations and this allows us to do more work with `numexpr`'s evaluate expression, like so -

```
s = (-2*(x<0))+1 # np.sign(x)
out = ne.evaluate('log( (abs(x)+1)**s)')
```

Computing `sign` using comparison gives us `s` in another way -

```
s = (-2*(x<0))+1
```

Finally, we can push this into the `numexpr` evaluate expression -

```
def mask_vectorized_numexpr_app2(x):
    return ne.evaluate('log( (abs(x)+1)**((-2*(x<0))+1))')
```

**Runtime test**

Loopy approach for comparison -

```
def loopy_app(x):
    out = np.empty_like(x)
    for i in range(len(out)):
        out[i] = f(x[i])
    return out
```

Timings and verification -

```
In [141]: x = np.random.randn(100000)
     ...: print np.allclose(loopy_app(x), mask_vectorized_app(x))
     ...: print np.allclose(loopy_app(x), mask_vectorized_numexpr_app(x))
     ...: print np.allclose(loopy_app(x), mask_vectorized_numexpr_app2(x))
     ...: 
True
True
True

In [142]: %timeit loopy_app(x)
     ...: %timeit mask_vectorized_numexpr_app(x)
     ...: %timeit mask_vectorized_numexpr_app2(x)
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 108 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.6 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 942 µs per loop
```

Using [`@user2685079's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277045/3293881) using `np.sign` to replace the first part and then with and without `numexpr` evaluation -

```
In [143]: %timeit np.sign(x) * np.log(1+abs(x))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.26 ms per loop

In [144]: %timeit np.sign(x) * ne.evaluate('log(1+abs(x))')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you add mine to your timings, please?

Comment: @piRSquared I don't have `numba`. Mind adding mine into yours?

Comment: Added the latest `app2`

Comment: @piRSquared Just making sure - You used the latest one that's one-liner, right?

Comment: Yes, I've included the function definitions in my answer to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

[**Using `numba`**](http://numba.pydata.org/)

> Numba gives you the power to speed up your applications with high performance functions written directly in Python. With a few annotations, array-oriented and math-heavy Python code can be just-in-time compiled to native machine instructions, similar in performance to C, C++ and Fortran, without having to switch languages or Python interpreters.
>
> Numba works by generating optimized machine code using the LLVM compiler infrastructure at import time, runtime, or statically (using the included pycc tool). Numba supports compilation of Python to run on either CPU or GPU hardware, and is designed to integrate with the Python scientific software stack.
>
> The Numba project is supported by Continuum Analytics and The Gordon and Betty Moore Foundation (Grant GBMF5423).

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def pir(x):
    a = np.empty_like(x)
    for i in range(a.size):
        x_ = x[i]
        _x = abs(x_)
        a[i] = np.sign(x_) * np.log(1 + _x)
    return a
```

---

**Accuracy**

```
np.isclose(pir(x), f(x)).all()

True
```

**Timing**

```
x = np.random.randn(100000)

# My proposal
%timeit pir(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 881 µs per loop

# OP test
%timeit f(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop

# Divakar-1
%timeit mask_vectorized_numexpr_app(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.97 ms per loop

# Divakar-2
%timeit mask_vectorized_numexpr_app2(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 621 µs per loop
```

**Function definitions**

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def pir(x):
    a = np.empty_like(x)
    for i in range(a.size):
        x_ = x[i]
        _x = abs(x_)
        a[i] = np.sign(x_) * np.log(1 + _x)
    return a

import numexpr as ne

def mask_vectorized_numexpr_app(x):
    out = np.empty_like(x)
    mask = x>=0
    mask_rev = ~mask

    x_masked = x[mask]
    x_rev_masked = x[mask_rev]
    out[mask] = ne.evaluate('log(x_masked+1)')
    out[mask_rev] = ne.evaluate('-log(-x_rev_masked+1)')
    return out

def mask_vectorized_numexpr_app2(x):
    return ne.evaluate('log( (abs(x)+1)**((-2*(x<0))+1))')


def f(x):
    return (x/abs(x)) * np.log(1+abs(x))
```

Comment: My latest app2 is a bit diferent :) Sorry for the trouble. Could you update? Don't think you need to list those again.

Comment: @Divakar no trouble :-).  That latest one is really fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly improve the speed of your second solution by using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
def loga(x):
    cond = [x >= 0, x < 0]
    choice = [np.log(x+1), -np.log(-x+1)]
    return np.select(cond, choice)

def logb(x):
    return np.where(x>=0, np.log(x+1), -np.log(-x+1))

In [16]: %timeit loga(arange(-1000,1000))
10000 loops, best of 3: 169 µs per loop

In [17]: %timeit logb(arange(-1000,1000))
10000 loops, best of 3: 98.3 µs per loop

In [18]: np.all(loga(arange(-1000,1000)) == logb(arange(-1000,1000)))
Out[18]: True
```